# PHP Event Calendar

Tags: php, mysql, events, calendar

I developed an own system with PHP for project management, but what I am kind of missing here is a well visualisation of what really is going on...So far the starting- and ending dates are shown of each project, but it's too difficult to read. I need a calendar or something like that.

I need to find a way to place those project dates with their ID in some kind of calendar, which shows all days each month. By clicking it, the user can see if a project is going on that date  or not.

Does somebody know any good tutorials or open source or whatever about a calendar like this? I've been searching around for tutorials but the ones I found were very basic.

EDIT

Something like this would be the best solution for me:

http://demo.helioscalendar.com/index.php?d=2013-01-21&m=1

Even better if I could program it in it on my own, but I don't know how something like this is set up.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=gantt+chart

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm looking into it now. Meanwhile, if you want to read my edit, maybe you can help me out again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if you want a normal calendar or a Gantt Chart but if a normal calendar will suffice then this is pretty good http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/